# Why does time report low user/system with MinGW?

Tags: windows, time, mingw

I am trying to time a program using the `time` utility provided in MinGW. The output reports real user and system time and for a serial version of the program I expected real time to be approximately close to user + system time. However I am observing barely no user or system time:

```
$ time bin/julia  > /dev/null

real    0m2.280s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.015s
```

While if I run the same program in an Ubuntu machine I get

```
$ time bin/julia > /dev/null

real    0m2.656s
user    0m2.632s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Both programs where compiled using `g++`, using version 7.2.0 for the incorrect MinGW case and version 5.4.0  for the ubuntu case.

Comment: You use MSys, it doesn't try nearly as hard to be compatible with the Unixes as Cygwin.  Fairly sure it uses GetProcessTimes() to obtain this measurement.   A rough guess is that the program is bogged down by I/O and not processor cycles.  Should be visible in Task Manager as well, look at the CPU column.

Comment: program is especially designed to be compute intense, it also has the option of delaying all I/O until completion, which yields the same result. Program is indeed visible in Task Manager, and running it for multiple minutes shows full CPU utilization for one core by the program. Can also imagine is MSys related but wonder if there is a way to fix it get around it.